# Emails sent from exim4 to gmail appear as read

Tags: exim, gmail

Have an exim4 smtp server setup on debian jessie. When emails are sent to gmail domains, for some reason they do not appear as unread in gmail. 
It puzzling as this will only happen for some accounts, specifically for a couple of daemons that are sending out emails on a regular basis.
I don't know if the problem lies within exim or gmail.

Comment: It is the MUA, not the MTA or originator, which maintains read flags.  Obviously you can't send an email and require the MUA to mark it read upon receipt.

Comment: Actually this is not entirely true. An IMAP or a Sieve server also maintain the seen/unseen state of a message, so it is set before any MUA even see the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read/unread status of a message is not carried by any SMTP header. And there is no concept of "message flags" in SMTP (I cant think of any...). Exim4 being an SMTP server only, I seriously doubt it had anything to do with the described behaviour. Gmail's rules are probably the motte obvious culprit.